# Displaying AtoD value on 16x2 LCD using MSP430

Tags: msp430, lcd

I am using a 16x2 LCD with an MSP430 and am unable to figure out how to print a value from my AtoD. My LCD is using the ST7066U driver, and the setup code for my LCD is this:

```
> #include <msp430.h>
> #include <delays.h>
> 
> #define CMD             0
> #define DATA      1
> 
> #define LCD_OUT       P2OUT
> #define LCD_DIR       P2DIR
> #define D4        BIT4
> #define D5        BIT5
> #define D6        BIT6
> #define D7        BIT7
> #define RS        BIT2
> #define EN        BIT3
> 
> // Function to pulse EN pin after data is written to accept it  void
> pulseEN(void) {   LCD_OUT |= EN;  delay_us(100);  LCD_OUT &= ~EN;
>   delay_us(100); }
> 
> //Function to write data/command to LCD void lcd_write(int value,int
> mode) {   if(mode == CMD)         LCD_OUT &= ~RS;                            
> // Set RS -> LOW for Command mode     else        LCD_OUT |= RS;              
> // Set RS -> HIGH for Data mode
> 
>         // Data has to be sent to LCD in 2 lots of 4 bits, as it is running in 4 bit mode     LCD_OUT = ((LCD_OUT & 0x0F) | (value &
> 0xF0));       // Write top 4 bits     pulseEN();  delay_us(10);
> 
>   LCD_OUT = ((LCD_OUT & 0x0F) | ((value << 4) & 0xF0));   // Write
> lower 4 bits  pulseEN();  delay_us(10); }
> 
> // Function to print a string on LCD void lcd_print(char *s) {
>   while(*s)   {       lcd_write(*s, DATA);        s++;    }
>         delay_ms(10); }
> 
> // Function to move cursor to desired position on LCD void
> lcd_setCursor(int row, int col) {     const row_offsets[] = { 0x00,
> 0x40};    lcd_write(0x80 | (col + row_offsets[row]), CMD);    delay_ms(1);
> }
> 
> // Function to clear the LCD void lcd_clr() {     lcd_write(0x01, CMD);  
> // Clear screen   delay_ms(5); }
> 
> // Initialize LCD void lcd_init() {   P2SEL &= ~(0x60);   LCD_DIR |=
> (D4+D5+D6+D7+RS+EN);  LCD_OUT &= ~(D4+D5+D6+D7+RS+EN);
> 
>   delay_ms(15);                                             // Wait for
> power up ( 15ms )     lcd_write(0x33, CMD);                              
> // Initialization Sequence 1  delay_ms(5);    lcd_write(0x32, CMD);     
> // Initialization Sequence 2  delay_ms(1);
> 
>   // All subsequent commands take 40 us to execute, except clear &
> cursor return (1.64 ms), may as well set the lot to 5ms just to be
> safe
> 
>   lcd_write(0x28, CMD);                                     // 4 bit
> mode, 2 line  delay_ms(5);
> 
>   lcd_write(0x0C, CMD);                                     // Display
> ON, Cursor OFF, Blink OFF     delay_ms(5);
> 
>   lcd_write(0x01, CMD);                                     // Clear
> screen    delay_ms(5);
> 
>   lcd_write(0x06, CMD);                                     // Auto
> Increment Cursor  delay_ms(5); }
```

In my main code, I read an AtoD value, but I am not too sure how to display it. The AtoD works fine, I can use debug mode in Crossworks and see the AtoD value is what I am expecting. I can display text on the LCD with something like this:

```
  lcd_setCursor(0,0);
  lcd_print("AtoD Test");
  lcd_setCursor(1,0);
  lcd_print("AtoD OK");
```

and that is fine. It will display characters I have written. But how do I get it to display a value I am reading from somewhere?

I am a complete novice at this, and the code for setting up the LCD was taken from [HERE](https://github.com/ticepd/msp430-examples/blob/master/28-simpleLCD/main.c) and edited slightly to fit my MSP and setup. Essentially, I just want to do something like

```
lcd_print("ADC_Result");
```

but when doing this, it just literally prints those words, and when trying

```
lcd_print("some text %*",ADC_Result);
```

I get an error saying too many arguments to lcd_print. I assume this means in my setup, I need to change something to the way lcd_print works, but not sure how to do this. Can someone please let me know how to edit this so I can do something along the lines of

```
lcd_print ("Some text %c", some_data);
```

and have it print something?

Answer (score 1):

The lcd_print() function you are using from the borrowed code only takes one parameter, a pointer to a null-terminated string. See line 51 of that code. But you want to output to the LCD using a printf() like style, which is a variadic function that takes a format string and any number of variables. This is the "error saying too many arguments" problem from the compiler.

To fix this problem, there are two general solutions: re-write lcd_print() so you can use it like printf(), or perform your string conversion before calling lcd_print().

Here is one solution that uses sprintf() function:

```c
// Create a buffer for sprintf to work with, use largest size you can afford
char sbuffer[BUFSIZE];
// Convert result to a string
sprintf(sbuffer, "ADC_Result = %d", some_data);
// Output string to LCD
lcd_print(sbuffer);
```